# Uncaught Error: Invalid Selector - #jqxCheckBox! Please, check whether the used ID or CSS Class name is correct

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jqxtree widgets

```
http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxtree/#demos/jqxtree/checkboxes.htm
```

And following `http://jsfiddle.net/jqwidgets/pMZS7/`

I am getting following error:

Uncaught Error: Invalid Selector - #jqxCheckBox! Please, check whether the used ID or CSS Class name is correct.

In fiddle it is working fine, i have implemented into my application so I am getting error there.

Comment: I don't get that error from the fiddle.

Comment: Well if nobody but you can see the place where the error is happening ... do you use that selector somewhere? What exactly does the code look like? "jqxCheckBox" is nowhere to be found in the fiddle.

Comment: @Pointy, I am using selector $('#jqxCheckBox').jqxCheckBox({ width: '200px', height: '25px', checked: true });

Comment: @Pointy, I just commented above code, this is working fine now for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is thrown when you try to select HTML Element by invalid ID i.e either you have typo in the ID or that HTML Element is not in the DOM.

Comment: It is happening becuase of HTML Element is not in the DOM. Thanks